# Convert Custom Collection string to JSON format

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert a string like this.
    `{0:{ Value:"0413-0415" }, 1:{ Value:"1-7800 LBO" }, 2:{ Value:"1-7804" }, 3:{ Value:"1-7805" }}`

To be a JSON string for Select2 which requires this format.
    `[{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement', attr: 'abc' }`

I would want to replace Value with id and replace description with text if description exists. If not Copy value to text as well as ID.

So the above would turn into
    `[{ id: "0413-0415", text: "0413-0415"}]`

How could i go about writing this in javascript?

I was able to get this to return a string in the format i want by writing this function.

```
function parseData(data)
{
    data = data.replace('{','[');
    data = data.replace(/,$/,"") + "]";
var re = /\{.*?\}/g;
var index, len;
var m = data.match(re);

correctedData = '[';
for (var el in m) {

    m[el] = m[el].replace('Value','id');
    m[el] = m[el].replace('Description','text');
    if(!m[el].includes("text:"))
    {
    var n = m[el].lastIndexOf('}') -1;
    m[el] = m[el].substring(0,n) + ', ' + m[el].replace('{','').replace('id','text'); 
    }
    correctedData = correctedData + m[el] + ', '

}
correctedData = correctedData.trim().replace(/,$/, "");
correctedData = correctedData.replace(/"/g, "'");
correctedData = correctedData + ']';

return correctedData;
}
```

However i know this is returning a string and using JSON.parse won't work because it says its not valid json. I looked at Select2 and took their example which also isn't valid json. Its just an array of objects. How can I get javascript to treat this as an array instead of a string.

JSFiddle of where i am currently at. https://jsfiddle.net/pricejt/d681sfew/

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: your kind of string is a valid object literal, but not a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, if surrounded with quotes.

Comment: you've tagged this question with c#, how do you generate this string? It shouldn't be too hard to find a module that outputs proper JSON.

Comment: I had C# tagged because i could format the data on the server side with C# before it gets to the UI side. Or i can format with javascript on the clent side. I also updated my answer to include the function i wrote to try to format the data i need.

Comment: why not choose a better data structure which is directly usable with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: @NinaScholz I am trying to make it work with Select2's array structure. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: @pricejt, yes, but where do you get the string from? can you change the structure?

Comment: @NinaScholz no i  can't i don't control the code from that application and that structure is its collection structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and take the parts for a new object, which could be collected in an array in the wanted format.

```js
var regex = /(\d+):{ Value:"([^"]*)"/g,
    str = '{0:{ Value:"0413-0415" }, 1:{ Value:"1-7800 LBO" }, 2:{ Value:"1-7804" }, 3:{ Value:"1-7805" }}',
    m,
    data = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m.length >= 2) {
        data.push({ id: m[1], text: m[2] });
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't refresh the page before i posed my final results.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this working. Final result here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/pricejt/d681sfew/2/

```
function parseData(data)
{
var correctedData = [];
data = data.replace('{','[');
data = data.replace(/,$/,"") + "]";
var re = /\{.*?\}/g;
var index, len;
var m = data.match(re);

for (var el in m) {

    m[el] = m[el].replace('Value','"id"');
    m[el] = m[el].replace('Description','"text"');
    if(!m[el].includes("text:"))
    {
    var n = m[el].lastIndexOf('}') -1;
    m[el] = m[el].substring(0,n) + ', ' + m[el].replace('{','').replace('id','text'); 
    }
    correctedData.push($.parseJSON(m[el]));

}

return correctedData;
}
```